# What's a good node.js / mongoose form builder?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

From using other frameworks I've gotten used to not building out and mapping forms to db objects manually.  Since using node.js and mongoose.  I'm looking for a form builder that allows the following:

1. automatically maps mongoose objects to form fields
2. handles both 'new' and 'update' use cases
3. allows class injection around form fields for styling
4. includes validation
5. allows one to add custom fields

Does anyone know of any such form builders for node.js, express, mongoose?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, or looked at it in depth, but https://github.com/oJshua/mongoose-forms looks like it may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of old discussion but I just wanted to recommend checking out Formage (npm: formage)

https://github.com/Empeeric/formage

Setup is easy and straightforward. You can check it out in matter of minutes and hopefully this can help you.

Comment: Last commit was from 6 hours ago and if you look at commit history you'll see lots of activity in past months.

Comment: Last commit is now 3 years ago. Seems dead.

Comment: Last commit is now 4 years ago. :(